# How to get the serial number of device in Android 10 programmatically?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

When I am using Build.getSerial() it throws an exception

getSerial: The user 10134 does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers.

this happens only when Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q

Any help to get serial number in android 10?

Comment: Maybe it's late, but you can see my gist, here you found a function that gives you the serial number for all android versions, follow this link here: https://gist.github.com/AlaaEddinAlbarghoth/d2b61f3fef22dbd00507eba531a8a352